# Wordpress Display Custom post types

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I'm a newbie in WordPress. I have created a custom post type for videos but I do not know how to display the post type in a page. For example I want when a user adds a video, he won't have to select a video template when publishing the video and when they open the published video, the page opens up with a video player instead of opening a page. I want something like a custom page with the video player ready that all I have to do is give the video player the url for the video.Already have the code for the video player. How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To make a default **[template file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates)** for all your custom post type posts or pages, you can name your template file `single-{your-cpt-name-here}.php` or `archive-{your-cpt-name-here}.php` and it will always default to this when viewing these posts or pages.

So for example in **`single-video.php`** you could put:

```
<?php query_posts( 'post_type=my_post_type' ); ?>
```

or instead make a custom query to shape your desired output:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $posts -> have_posts() ) {
    while ( $posts -> have_posts() ) {

        the_content();
        // Or your video player code here

    }
}
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

In your custom loop like the example above, there's lots of available **[template tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags)** (like `the_content`) to choose from in Wordpress.

Answer (score 5):

**Write Code In Functions.php**

```
    function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'Movies',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Movies' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Movie' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'Movies'),
    )
);
```

**Now Write This Code Where You Want To show**

```
    <?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'Movies', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    the_title();
    echo '<div class="entry-content">';
    the_content();
    echo '</div>';
    endwhile;
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

After you created the CPT, do this for showing single posts of your CPT:

- Duplicate the `single.php` file in your template and rename it like
  `single-{post_type}.php` (eg. `single-movie.php`)
- Remember to flush the permalinks from WordPress!

You can get more details from [this post](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/08/27/showing-single-posts-of-a-custom-post-type-in-wordpress/)

- Now if you want to show a list of CPT you can use [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) with args:

  `$args = array(
  ...
  'post_type' => 'movie'
  )`

Check [this post](https://coderpills.wordpress.com/2014/08/27/showing-a-list-of-custom-post-type-using-get_posts-loop-in-wordpress/) for further details.